# Error when trying to add a column to a spark dataframe from another dataframe's column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to `PySpark`, and I want to add a column to a Spark `DataFrame` from another `DataFrame`'s column. The structure of the column I want to add is such that each row is an array of integers. I am receiving the following error when attempting to do so:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [61, 70, 78, 83, 77]
```

Can anyone advise on how to solve this issue?